# How do I store image ID in query-string?

Tags: php, query-string

I've used "ImageFlow" on my personal website, and what I want to do is that when you click on an image, another page opens with the ID of the image stored in a query-string like when you are using $_get in a form. For example:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/details.php?id=001`
Then I'm going to use some databases to print some information on the page like:

```
Place: Lake Otawa
Date: 1/1-2011
```

And so on...
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to answer without any additional code.
Where is the image id stored?

Guessing this would do:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/image.php?id=<?php echo $image_id;?>"><img src="image/path.jpg" target="_blank"/></a>
```

Comment: Take this as an example:
<img src="img1.jpg" id="img1" longdesc="details.php?id=ID_GOES_HERE>
How can I drag the ID from that without having to type it manually? Maybe this is not really necessary :D